# Misunderstanding main method/the point of "public static void main(String[] args)"

Tags: java, constructor

I have an assignment to write a class with a constructor + various methods that returns values to the main class.

My code never compiles correctly either due to error:cannot find simple or illegal start of expression.

I believe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to make a constructor, what exactly the main method is, and how one class calls another.

**Assignment:**

*Suppose that you are given the following Driver class, which includes a main method:*

```
public class Driver {   
    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        double distance = 400.48;
        double fuel = 21.4;
        AutoTrip myTrip = new AutoTrip(distance, fuel);
        System.out.print("My car traveled " + myTrip.getDistance() + " miles");
        System.out.println("on " + myTrip.getFuel() + " gallons of gasoline.");
        double mileage = myTrip.getMPG(); // get miles per gallon
        System.out.println("My mileage was " + mileage + ".");  
    } 
}
```

*Now suppose that executing main produces the following output:
My car traveled 400.48 miles on 21.4 gallons of gasoline.

My mileage was 18.714018691588787.

Implement the AutoTrip class so that it produces the indicated output.*

**My code:**

```
public class AutoTrip { 
    public AutoTrip(double distance, double fuel){
         this.distance = distance;
         this.fuel = fuel;
     }

     public double getDistance(){
         return distance;
     }

     public double getFuel(){
       return fuel;
     }

     public double getMPG(){
        return distance / fuel;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are forgetting to add your variables in your class AutoTrip

```
public class AutoTrip {
    private double distance; // Missing var
    private double fuel; // Missing var

    public AutoTrip(double distance, double fuel) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.fuel = fuel;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public double getFuel() {
        return fuel;
    }

    public double getMPG() {
        return distance / fuel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah I see. This whole time I thought the variables were being defined IN the constructor itself.
I understand entirely now, thank you!